# pause a video (mp4) running inside a uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, audio, uiwebview

I am loading videos(mp4) and Audio(mp3) files into a UIwebview.
It's straight forward and works nicely

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: videoURL cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 30.0];  
[webView loadRequest: request];  
[request release];
```

**Question:**
How do I prevent the video / audio from autoplay ?
I want the video to pause and let the user click "play" assuming he wants to play it.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the media file play automatically when viewed from a stand-alone browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question

using the following code will do the job

> `NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html><head><style></style></head><body><video id='video_with_controls' height='438' width='672' controls autobuffer autoplay='false'><source src='%@' title='' poster='icon2.png' type='video/mp4' durationHint='durationofvideo'/></video><ul></body></html>",videoURL];`

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[webView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the video tag in your UIWebView to play the video. You'll have to use javascript to control the video element within your UIWebView. You can use the [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:] method to execute the javascript needed to pause the video. Then it should just be a matter of writing the JS to look up the video element on the page and call pause() on it.